# updating a youtube video (api v3) returns 'video not found' but works in their API explorer

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to update the description on my youtube video via some python code.
This is my PUT request

body (this is converted to a json string):

```
{'id': <the video's youtube id>,
 'snippet': {
    'categoryId': <category id>,
    'channelId': <channel id>,
    'description': 'new title',
    'title': 'new title'
}}
```

headers:

```
{'Authorization': 'Bearer <access token given via the oauth flow>'
```

url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=<my_youtube_api_key>
```

}

and I'm getting this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "message": "Video not found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Video not found"
 }
}
```

The odd thing is that the same query works from the API explorer on this page: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update

I'm copying and pasting the params from my python code, so it's not like a youtube video with that id doesn't actually exist.

What's going on?

Comment: inexplicably, this is working now. I'll post an explanation as soon as I figure it out

Comment: The only change I see is this additional header: `'Content-Type':'application/json'`

Answer (score 1):

The only change I've made is add the following header:
`'Content-Type':'application/json'`

and the API call works now.